# Use DynamoDB mapper for multiple key query

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have searched this on Google for a while but did not get a specific answer.

Lets say I have a table storing the people information, it uses PeopleId as the hash key. Is there a way to construct a query to return the person if his Id is 1 or 2?

Looks like I can use BatchGetItem to do such things, but will it have higher latency?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have any conditions of the Partition Key part of your Primary Key in DynamoDB. You can on the Sort Key.

So, you would either have to do GetItem twice, or use BatchGetItem.

Comment: Thanks! I just found there is a method expression.withFilterExpression("id=x or id=y"), but not sure if this can reduce latency.http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Methods.html#d0e31877

Comment: The filter expression cannot be applied to the Partition Key, only to the Sort Key. For a DynamoDB query, you gotta have the precise Partition Key and you cannot have any conditions on it.

Comment: Hi Nick, I found the filterExpression works on every attribute, but it happens after getting result from dynamoDB and before returning results to client. The condition you mentioned works on both sort keys and hashkeys and will help on reduce latency. Thanks!